# what is the metadata xml tag for Service Presence Statuses Access in salesforce?

Tags: metadata, omnichannel

[image]

I could not get this tag anywhere ?  Any idea?
I see this link
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_presenceuserconfig.htm
but i am trying to map those staus in profile or permission set than the presece configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Metadata API and this idea is pending.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdq3UUAR/add-service-presence-statuses-access-to-metadata-api